# trouble with window.resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a page that contains a jquery tab element with three tabs. Within that element, there is a map (tab 1 - PolyMap), chart (tab 2 - Devexpress), and data grid (tab 3 - Devexpress). The site itself is built on Foundation 4 to provide responsive design. Using foundation, the width and height of the page will change when the screen size changes, but the actual map and graph elements were not changing. I implemented the following code to cause the map and graph to automatically resize when the screen size changes (i.e portrait-landscape), or when the page is initially loaded.

I am fairly new to javascript programming, so I am still trying to learn the intricacies of the differences between browsers. I typically use Chrome to develop, and so I developed the code based on what works in Chrome. The issue that I am running into is that when I now test in IE or Firfox (both current releases), I am getting differing results. In IE, both elements are loaded with 0px height. In Firefox, the map is loaded correctly (the tab that is shown by default), but the chart is loaded with a 0px height (the chart tab is initially not shown). If the screen size changes, the script fires and the size is immediately corrected, so I am guessing that it is either an issue with using `$(window).load`, or the code is firing before the page is loaded completely in IE or Firefox (although I have a hard time understanding how it would work correctly in Chrome).

Are there any suggestions - and remember, i am new, so if the entire code block should be reworked, I am completely open to that- I want to learn...

Code (appears immediately before closing html tag):

```
    function ResizeMap() {
        var mPadding = $('#MapContent').css("padding");
        mPadding = mPadding.substring(0, mPadding.length - 2);
        mPadding = mPadding * 2;
        if (MapContent.offsetWidth > 970) {
            var nWidth = 970-mPadding;
            var nHeight = 650;
        } else {
            var nWidth = MapContent.offsetWidth-mPadding;
            var nHeight = nWidth * (650/(970-mPadding));
        }
        $('#map').width(nWidth);
        $('#map').height(nHeight);
    }
    function ResizeChart() {
        var cPadding = $('#ChartContent').css("padding");
        cPadding = cPadding.substring(0, cPadding.length - 2);
        cPadding = cPadding * 2;
        if (ChartContent.offsetWidth > 970) {
            var nWidth = 970-cPadding;
            var nHeight = 650;
        } else {
            var nWidth = ChartContent.offsetWidth-cPadding;
            var nHeight = nWidth * (650/(970-cPadding));
        }
        chart.SetWidth(nWidth);
        chart.SetHeight(nHeight);
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        ResizeMap();
        ResizeChart();
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
        ResizeMap();
        ResizeChart();
    });
```

Comment: @Joe They're element IDs, I think that automatically creates `window.<id>` variables.

Comment: MapContent and ChartContent are both DIV elements that are set with 100% width using CSS